# Add own customize settings for stylecop in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, stylecop

I have installed the Visual StyleCop from Extension and Updates in VS2015, But in VS2013 I used to copy my own customized rules file(Settings.StyleCop) for stylecop in C:\Program Files (x86)\StyleCop 4.7 folder but I am not able to do this in VS2015.

Please help me to where I have to copy the Settings.StyleCop file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the folder to own customized rules file(Settings.StyleCop) for Visual  stylecop in VS 2015 it is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions folder in my system having a random generated(encrypted) file name. in my case it was (szaq1l3s.2zm)

Answer (score 0):

That traditional style cop has been outdated for over a year. It's been stuck on 4.7. But I think you can just take that stylecop.settings file and copy it to the root of your solutions folder. theoretically can also copy that settings file to each individual folder within your solution, and it will override the one higher.

The better bet is to start to learn to use the stylecop.analyzers project found in NuGet. It's meant to work really well with Visual Studio 2015. You customize it by editing what is called the active rule set.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the answer if you run build with "Diagnostic" logging (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->Dropdown "MSbuild project build output verbosity"), then in the output window search for string:

```
StyleCopOverrideSettingsFile = ....
```